# XPage-Page Cant be displayed error after upgrading to Domino 9.0.1 from 8.5.3

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib, domino-designer-eclipse

I have recently started working with Xpages. The sample Xpage which i created in version 8.5.3 is not working after I upgraded the domino to 9.0.1. After the upgrade even a local test page is giving a 404 error. On the server its giving a Page not found error. I have done the below,

1. Checked the ACL for default
2. Checked and changed the http port number
3. Enabled the auto build
4. marked the Xpage as available to public access
5. The trace log does not display anything.

seems like I am missing something very obvious. Please enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: Did you build the project (Designer menu Project/Build Project or Project/Build Automatically is set)? Also try menu Project/Clean.

Comment: Yes, i did. I did clean and build automatically is set.

Comment: Also, the URL is like this http://nserver70:8082/HelloWorld.nsf/Home.xsp. The nserver70 is the server name. The server name with domain name is NSERVER70/AS400. I tried with the IP address also.

Comment: What does the browser show exactly when you access the server URL? Does it show you a Domino generated error page?

Comment: What's in log.nsf and domlog.nsf?

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten  It just give me the "This Page can't be displayed" message.

Comment: Are you sure that the Domino server is set to respond on port 8082?

Comment: Are you using Internet Sites? Any web rules? Also remember that the name of the XPage is case sensitive (but it also was on the previous server....). What does it say on the server console (specifically the URL - is it what you expect...)?

Comment: Be sure to check the Errors panel in Domino Designer.  Check the design from the Package Explorer view and look fora  red X next to any element.  You may need to project build the entire workspace, not just the current db.  Also check the XPages log on the server in the domino\data\IBM_Technical_Support folder for more detailed error mesages.